# Swift UI view only displaying one record instead of the List of record

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui, async-await, viewmodel

I'm using Swift UI . I'm using async and await to handle the concurrency. I am trying to display list of product record .I have 30 record into json here is the json link https://dummyjson.com/products. and I got the 30 record when I debug it but when I run the app , **It only displaying one record only . I am wondering where is mistake or changes , I need to make .**

Here is my model ..

```
import Foundation

// MARK: - Welcome
struct ProductData: Codable, Hashable {
    let products: [Product]
}

// MARK: - Product
struct Product: Codable, Hashable {
    let id: Int
    let title, description: String
    let price: Int
    let discountPercentage, rating: Double
    let stock: Int
    let brand, category: String
    let thumbnail: String
    let images: [String]
}
```

Here is my view model code ..

```
@MainActor
final class ProductListViewModel {

    @Published private(set) var productLists: [ProductData] = []
    @Published private(set) var customError: NetworkError?
    @Published private(set) var refreshing = true
    @Published var isErrorOccured = false

    private let repository: ProductRepository
    init(repository: ProductRepository) {
        self.repository = repository
    }
}
extension ProductListViewModel: ProductListViewModelAction {
    func getProductList(urlStr: String) async {
            refreshing = true
            guard let url = URL(string: urlStr) else {
            self.customError = NetworkError.invalidURL
            refreshing = false
            isErrorOccured = false
            return
        }
        do {
            let lists = try await repository.getList(for: url)
            refreshing = false
            isErrorOccured = false
            productLists = [lists]

        } catch {
            refreshing = false
            isErrorOccured = true
            customError = error as? NetworkError
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my view ..

```
import SwiftUI

struct ProductListView: View {
    
    @StateObject var viewModel = ProductListViewModel(repository: ProductRepositoryImplementation(networkManager: NetworkManager()))

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                if viewModel.customError != nil && !viewModel.refreshing {
                    alertView()
                } else {
                    if viewModel.refreshing {
                        progressView()
                    }
                    if viewModel.productLists.count > 0 && !viewModel.refreshing {

                        List(viewModel.productLists, id: \.self) { product in
                            ProductListViewCell(productData: product)

                        } .listStyle(.grouped)
                    }
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    getToolBarView()
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle(Text("Product List"))
        }.task{
            await getDataFromAPI()
        }
        .refreshable {
            await getDataFromAPI()
        }
    }

    func getDataFromAPI() async {
        await viewModel.getProductList(urlStr: NetworkURL.productUrl)
    }

    @ViewBuilder
    func getToolBarView() -> some View {
        Button {
            Task{
                await getDataFromAPI()
            }
        } label: {
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "arrow.clockwise")
                    .padding(.all, 10.0)
            }.fixedSize()
        }
        .cornerRadius(5.0)
    }

    @ViewBuilder
    func progressView() -> some View {
        VStack{
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                .fill(.white)
                .frame(height: 180)
                .overlay {
                    VStack {
                        ProgressView().padding(50)
                        Text("Please Wait Message").font(.headline)
                    }
                }
        }
    }

    @ViewBuilder
    func alertView() -> some View {
        Text("").alert(isPresented: $viewModel.isErrorOccured) {
            Alert(title: Text("General_Error"), message: Text(viewModel.customError?.localizedDescription ?? ""),dismissButton: .default(Text("Okay")))
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my cell view ..

```
import SwiftUI

struct ProductListViewCell: View {
    let productData: ProductData
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            if let url = URL(string: productData.products.first?.thumbnail ?? ""){
                ProductAsyncImageView(url: url)
                    .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                    .mask(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16))
            }
            VStack(alignment: .leading,spacing: 5){
                Text("Product Name: " +  (productData.products.first?.title ?? ""))
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    .font(.headline)

                Text("Product Description: " + (productData.products.first?.description ?? ""))
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)


                Text("Product Price: " + String(productData.products.first?.price ?? 0))
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    .font(.subheadline)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the result in the debug ..

[image: Debug result]

Here is the screenshot..Only one record is displayed.

[image]

Comment: what is the best way to correct  this problem .

Comment: I got the expected result when I directly pass the Product model but I want pass it though the ProductData model @Rob

Comment: BTW, in the future, I would encourage you to post a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), making it both “minimal” by removing unnecessary kruft (like unused protocols, irrelevant image code, unnecessary custom error types, alerts, progress views, network manager, etc.), but also “reproducible” by including the bare essentials to reproduce your output. It took an unnecessary amount of effort just to reproduce your output. That’s likely why you got the two “close”/“down” votes.

Comment: Thanks @Rob I will follow it next question.

Comment: since this is swiftui you should be using View structs and @State, and not view model objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `productLists = [lists]` creates an array with one item in it. Now, that `ProductData` might have thirty products in it, but `ProductListViewCell` then creates a cell for only the first product in that `ProductData`. Thus, only one item will be shown.

I would suggest product list view model should probably just take an array of products:

```swift
final class ProductListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published private(set) var products: [Product] = []    // an array of products

    …
}

extension ProductListViewModel {
    func getProductList(urlStr: String) async {
        refreshing = true
        guard let url = URL(string: urlStr) else { … }

        do {
            let productList = try await repository.getList(for: url)
            refreshing = false
            isErrorOccured = false
            products = productList.products                 // get the list of products
        } catch {
            …
        }
    }
}
```

The then the `ProductListView` would show this array of `Product`:

```swift
struct ProductListView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = …
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                …
                if viewModel.products.count > 0 && !viewModel.refreshing {
                    List(viewModel.products, id: \.self) { product in
                        ProductListViewCell(product: product)
                    } .listStyle(.grouped)
                }
            }
}
```

The cell then just takes a `Product`:

```swift
struct ProductListViewCell: View {
    let product: Product
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            if let url = URL(string: product.thumbnail) { … }

            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {
                Text("Product Name: \(product.title)")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    .font(.headline)
                
                Text("Product Description: \(product.description)")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                
                Text("Product Price: \(product.price)")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    .font(.subheadline)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Yielding:

[image]

---

Now, there are lots of ways of skinning the cat: You can use your `ProductData` if you want. But the key take-home message is that `ProductListViewCell` is for showing a single `Product` so it does not make sense to give it a whole `ProductData` and only access the `first` product in that array of 30 products contained within the `ProductData`.